# significance of two phases - "query then fetch" with default number of shards as 1

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there any significance for  search to be executed in two phases - "query then fetch" when the default number of shards as 1 ( starting from 7.x ) ? leaving the cases of considering replicas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**query than fetch** is the default search type and yes you are right in case of single primary shard it doesn't make a difference whether you use this default or **DFS Query Then Fetch** as result will be the same.

Refer [Elastic official blog on difference b/w query than fetch and DFS query than fetch](https://www.elastic.co/blog/understanding-query-then-fetch-vs-dfs-query-then-fetch).

But what if you increase or change the default number of the primary shards, then you will see the difference in your search results as in this case Elaticsearch will have to query more than shards(it can be primary or replica shard).

**You should not be confused with Replicas as it just contains the copy of primary shard and when the search happens it wither query the primary shard or replica shard, so in this case it will not make any difference as at the end its just a shard which is being queried.**

Comment: point taken , the role of coordinating node fades away , and there is no point to do the aggregation in two places now ( one in data node) and again in coordinating node. Is there a way to suppress this ?

Comment: @Nag, nope co-ordinating node will still be there, but as there is just one shard it will get the data from that shard and send back the result and you can't suppress this unless your co-ordinating node happens to be the same data node which contains the data. btw internode communication is pretty fast, Not sure why you want to suppress this and what is your use-case.